How to read cookie in API route that was set in server.js on Next 14
Inside my server.js file on my Next 14 application I have:
    // Middleware to extract tenant from subdomain
    server.use((req, res, next) => {
        const hostname = req.hostname;
        const subdomain = hostname.split('.')[0]; // Assumes format `tenant.domain.com`
        res.cookie('tenant', subdomain, {
            httpOnly: false,
            path: '/',
            secure: true,
            sameSite: 'strict',
            domain: `.localhost:${port}`,
        });
        next();
    });


and I'm trying to access that cookie on an API route
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';

type NextApiRequestWithTenant = NextApiRequest & { tenant: string };

export async function GET(req: NextApiRequestWithTenant, res: NextApiResponse) {
    // Assuming middleware adds tenant to the request object
    const tenant = Cookies.get('tenant');
    console.log('[TENANT API]', Cookies);
    return NextResponse.json({ tenant, data: 'some data' });
}


However I am getting an empty object for my cookies.
I have verified that the cookie is being set on the server.js middleware, but I'm not sure why I can't access that cookie on my API route.

Fixed it, I was trying to access server cookies with a client cookie library,
changed my API route to:


import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

type NextApiRequestWithTenant = NextApiRequest & { tenant: string };

export async function GET(req: NextApiRequestWithTenant, res: NextApiResponse) {
    // access cookie and get tenant
    const tenantCookie = req?.cookies?._parsed?.get('tenant').value;
    return NextResponse.json({ tenant: tenantCookie, data: 'some data' });
}




Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
